# Is that possible to make radiobuttons on scrollview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I want to make radio buttons on `UIScrollView`. When I try to make it on `UIView` then it works perfectly but when i tried on `UIScrollView` then the same code will work as checkboxes. So is there any way to make radio buttons on `UIScrollView`?

I am using this code for scrollview

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        UIButton *but = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [but setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"emptycheckbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [but setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [but setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 33)];
        [but setCenter:CGPointMake( 50,  i*40+20 )];
        [but addTarget:self action:@selector(checkboxButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [scrollView addSubview:but];

        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
        [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(200,1000)];
    }


- (IBAction)checkboxButton:(UIButton *)button{

    for (UIButton *but in [self.view subviews]) {
        if ([but isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] && ![but isEqual:button]) {
            [but setSelected:NO];
        }
    }
    if (!button.selected) {
        button.selected = !button.selected;
    }
}
```

I an using this code for `UIView`

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        UIButton *but = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [but setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"emptycheckbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [but setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [but setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 33)];
        [but setCenter:CGPointMake( 50,  i*40+20 )];
        [but addTarget:self action:@selector(checkboxButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:but];


    }


- (IBAction)checkboxButton:(UIButton *)button{

    for (UIButton *but in [self.view subviews]) {
        if ([but isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] && ![but isEqual:button]) {
            [but setSelected:NO];
        }
    }
    if (!button.selected) {
        button.selected = !button.selected;
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't understand what you are doing with the `[self.view subviews]` for loop. The button parameter in `checkboxButton:` is the button whose state needs to be toggled. Simply `button.selected = !button.selected` should be enough.

Comment: @Akshay :Its because you need to toggle all the buttons and set state for a single button, which gives the appearance of a radio button where only one is selected at all times

Comment: @shivangi: I think your buttons are subviews of the scroll view. Iterate the loop to get the scrollview and then get subviews of the scrollview which are of type UIButtons. If you don't get it then leave a comment i will add more info.

Comment: Ah! got it! @Shivangi: What does "then the same code will work as checkboxes" mean?

Comment: Akshay:It means the other button doesn't get de-selected like radio buttons and clicking the other buttons make it behave more like check boxes, which toggle states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for scrollview should be:

```
for (UIButton *but in [scrollview subviews]) {...

NOT: for (UIButton *but in [self.view subviews]) {...
```